# The Twenty Doors! (ROOM 1)

Tags: cipher

This is part of [The Twenty Doors](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%22The+Twenty+Doors%22) series.

The next one is [The Twenty Doors! (ROOM 2)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17198/the-twenty-doors-room-2)

---

You stand in a small, dark room. You have no idea where you are. Then, you see a message in front of you.

> Welcome to the dungeon!
>
> In each room, there is some paper, a hint, a door and a keypad. You must decipher the paper, using the hint, and enter what you think the answer is into the keypad. But don't answer wrong, or you will DIE!!!
>
> Have fun, if you can...
>
> - Dr. X

**ROOM 1:**

You look at the paper:

> uipefvyq

Then, you see that the hint is carved into the wall: `Hello, over and over`.
The keypad has 9 numbers and an [ENTER] button.

Comment: You might want to change the title if there are going to be 19 more of these. Perhaps "The first of twenty doors!"

Comment: It seems that there are 2 answers, both that seem viable..But which one is correct? I suggest that you double check the future puzzles (if there are to be 20) that there is only 1 unique answer otherwise they might be considered as "too broad" or possibly "opinion based". [Which can result in a closed question]

Comment: I suggest you break this puzzle into separate questions (either now or after the 2nd part) as the question and the amount of answers provided will become very large (very quickly) if you keep building on top of it. It will also become harder to understand the flow of answers and who should be credited. You can always reference back to this question in your future ones with a link. (Especially if the only thing carried forward is the story). You could also mention if the previous questions answer could be important or not.

Comment: @MarkN Good idea. I will do it now.

Comment: so what are the nine numbers?... :) ... 0, 44, 35, 99999, 23457, 6, 42, 49, and 1234567890

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Room 1:

> The code is 14, if we decipher uipefvyq with the Vigenere cipher 'hello', we get neetruof, which is fourteen backwards.

I hope I won't DIE...

Comment: I actually used a one-time pad with the key HelloHello, but this works!

Comment: @Kslkgh, The difference between Vigenere and OTP is that in Vigenere the key repeats.

Comment: @hildred Yeah, I misused the OTP cipher a bit. But only realised once I was coming back from work, and didn't want to change the key that some people were cracking.

Answer (score 27):

Credit to [Cerberus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/17168/9000) for decoding the message. However, I think the conclusion in that answer is wrong. I think it should be

> 41

because

> it's 14 backwards

Comment: I did actually do fourteen, but this is still a good answer.

Comment: That actually a clever observation +1

Answer (score 5):

Credit to both asdfffff and Cerberus, but I think that both of you were part of the way there.

Cerberus pointing out that:

> Decrypting uipefvyq gives you neetruof

and asdfffff pointing out

> 41 would be fourteen backwards!

But you skipped the last part of the hint!

I think the answer would be:

> 4141

Becuase:

> It is 41 over and over.

Comment: you may need to double the length as that is only a single repeat, and doubling matches the length of the hint.

Comment: The 'over and over' part was referencing the use the Vigenere cipher with 'hello', however your answer does seem to be possible as well.

Comment: It might as well be 41411414, which is 41 over and over AND 14 over and over. But if we're going to do that, just make it 4141141441411414, which is 41411414 over and over...

Comment: @MarkN Yeah, I misused the OTP cipher.