# The Twenty Doors! (ROOM 2)

Tags: cipher

This is part of [The Twenty Doors](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%22The+Twenty+Doors%22) series.

The previous one is [The Twenty Doors! (ROOM 1)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/17167/9000)

The next one is [The Twenty Doors! (ROOM 3)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17313/the-twenty-doors-room-3)

---

**ROOM 2:**

After entering the first door, you find yourself in a bigger room. You look at the keypad.

```
[+] [-] [X]
[÷] [∞] [±]
  [ENTER]
```

You look around the room. Then, you see the paper.

> KDKGEOVB

And, as before, there is a hint carved into the wall - `A to Z Alphabet`

This time, the answer seems to be a maths symbol. Or symbols. Still, you've got this far, so you may as well try.

**HINT 1:**

> There is only one symbol involved.

**HINT 2:**

> A to Z was not required. It could have been A to B, I to C or anything. Each one changes the encrypted text. Now, which cipher is that?

**HINT 3:**

> It is an eight-letter word.

**HINT 4:**

> AAAABABAAAAABABABAAAAAABB I love bacon.

**MEGA HINT:**

> The cipher used above is called Baconian.

The next door will be added when the current door is solved!

Comment: Since these are now going to be separate puzzles, I don't think this is a semi-interactive puzzle anymore, is it?

Comment: @BaileyM Good point, I hadn't thought of that. I'll remove the tags.

Comment: I did the same thing myself with my current not-actually-a-semi-interactive puzzle. :) These look like a lot of fun, by the way!

Comment: No freebies here: ADDITION, SUBTRACT, MULTIPLY, DIVIDING, INFINITY all have eight letters and are all plausible plaintext.

Comment: @lorimer Yup, I took care when choosing the symbols for this keypad!

Comment: Maybe also noteworthy, Alphabet is eight letters too

Comment: So when this puzzle was first posted, I used a dictionary of 8 letter words and tried to find any word that matched the pattern of the ciphertext (possibly reversed, rotated, etc). I didn't really see a word that matched the symbols, but since the hints seem like subsitution, maybe someone else wants to dig through ~800 words. https://gist.github.com/ehotinger/88d31cbe18e29e89f489

It's possible that I'm missing a word or the word is two words, compressed/scrambled, etc. though.

Comment: @EricHotinger Check the comments on your GitHub.

Comment: @Kslkgh Oh, bummer. Anyway - you may want to add more hints (is it an 8 letter word, does the cipher text guarantee K = K in each spot, ...). There are too many possible answers which could be right, which is why there are so many answers below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We should press

> INFINITY

Deciphering AAAABABAAAAABABABAAAAAABB gives:

> **BIFID** using the Baconian Cipher

Deciphering KDKGEOVB:

> Using Bifid cipher with **Alphabet** as a key and Translate **A** to **Z** gives **INFINITY**

Comment: Could you explain this a little? My understanding of a Bifid cipher is that the key couldn't have repeated letters? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifid_cipher

Comment: @Cain - You are correct.  The second A in "alphabet" is just ignored when you use a deciphering page like [this one](http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/bifid.php).

Comment: I thought this was the answer, I just had no reason besides "OMIGOSH IT'S AN INFINITY BUTTON I WANNA PRESS ITTTTT"

Comment: can you help me with it: I use http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/bifid.php to decipher the BIFID-encoded message KDKGEOVB. The key is : Alphabet which changes to Zlphabet (or Zlphzbet?). The decrypted message wouldn't be infinity. Which point am I missing?

Answer (score 9):

Here's an attempt:

> Convert each letter to it's numerical place in the alphabet. A=1, B=2, Z=26. That gives the following numbers: `[11,4,11,7,5,15,22,2]`

I'm not sure which direction is correct here but I suspect what we want is

> $11\times4\div11+7\times5-15-22-2$ because that's $0$ if you use infix notation that takes into account the order of operations.

If that's true, then the button presses would be:

> $\times\div+\times---\ \mathrm{ENTER}$

Interestingly, If instead we use A=0 and the calculator uses immediate execution, the solution is

> The same! $\left(\left(\left(\left(10\times3\right)\div10\right)+6\right)\times4\right)-14-21-1=0$
> Unless, of course, the intended answer is $2$ because this is the second room. In that case, we could change it slightly at the end: $\left(\left(\left(\left(10\times3\right)\div10\right)+6\right)\times4\right)-14-21+1=2$

Comment: But what if it's similar to computers, where A = 0 :O!

Comment: Also, what if it's in RPN? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

Comment: @MarkN How about this for mindblowing: Using $E$ for enter, the buttons are $\times E \div E + E \times E - - - E $. Does that look familiar? It's the same operations with an Enter after each one.

Comment: @Cain There are no means that I can detect for determining if what I'm only assuming is a calculator uses RPN. Therefore, I choose to go with infix notation instead as it is more common so far as I know.

Comment: Although, unless this is a fancy calculator, it doesn't obey the order of operations (it performs each stage of the calculation as soon as it is entered).  So you will end up with $(11\times4\div11+7)\times5-15-22-2 =16$.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I use scientific calculators that obey the order or operations. However, given that this is found in a dungeon, it may not be so advanced.

Comment: @EngineerToast I don't understand what you are trying to say in your previous comment :s?

Comment: @MarkN If A=0, then you have the same order of operations except for immediate execution.

Comment: Nice idea, but no. 'A-Z alphabet' is important.

Comment: Check the hint for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is a very simplistic guess, but here goes.

> Perhaps the piece of paper with KDKGEOVB is a red herring and the clue is just the words 'A to Z Alphabet'. Among the symbols we have, only one of the symbols is also an alphabet, i.e. 'X'. We read it as multiplication, but the correct symbol is the only one which is a part of the English alphabet.
> So I would press 'X', then 'ENTER'.

Comment: It looks like a capital X, in a capital A to Z Alphabet.

Comment: Nice answer, but no.

Answer (score 0):

The lack of food, water and day light, forced me to make this desperate attempt and so I'll probably die

> Deciphering `KDKGEOVB` using a this key `pzsbotsl` (which came out of thin air) with the vigenere cipher you get `ADDITION`, so I'd press the pluss sign and hit enter