# The Twenty Doors! (ROOM 6)

Tags: cipher

This is part of [The Twenty Doors](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%22The+Twenty+Doors%22) series. 

The previous one is [The Twenty Doors! (ROOM 5)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17423/the-twenty-doors-room-5/)

The next one is [The Twenty Doors (ROOM 7)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18345/the-twenty-doors-room-7/)

---

You go through door 5, and see a rather unusual keypad.

`[♣][♦][♠][♥]
   [ENTER]`

The paper has been put on the left wall from when you come in, rotated by 90º.

> Znw qbty zx uxtw wlb ibnsqh thygpozg nkbveni Rnn-Imed xo qjw qytjfa osa.

And, as always, a hint has been carved into the wall.

`Caesar spun in a 3 width box. That's the answer to the alphabet, though the key and alphabet are reversed. And, 123456789 could well be a key, will you decipher it, we will see...`

What symbol should you press?

This is the most cryptic one so far, and also hardest to decipher. I want every part of this puzzle explained!

The next door will be added when this door is solved!

Comment: please let me know in room 5 what was the cipher for the wall carving.

Comment: @CodeNewbie I'm sorry to admit that I have forgotten! That's why I added the second hint. I believe it was the Gronsfeld cipher, but I can't find any legible text produced from that.

Comment: rotated in which direction?

Comment: @Nyk232 It's rather cryptic. Look through the sentence carefully. I took care to make this one the hardest yet.

Comment: I can't wait for the next room! :)

Comment: No more rooms? :(

Comment: @Davide Been away, and WiFi was down. Next room will be here soon!

Comment: @Davide And [here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18345/the-twenty-doors-room-7/) it is!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My answer (sorry for my english) :

First part :

> Caesar spun in a 3 width box.

So

> Use rotate cipher with a 90° left rotation and a box width of 3 applied to Caesar gives you **eraacs**.

Then second part :

> That's the answer to the alphabet, though the key and alphabet are reversed. And, 123456789 could well be a key,

So using

> a Gronsfeld Cipher with a key of 123456789 and **eraacs** as keyword for the alphabet, remembering to reverse the keywords the alphabet

You decrypt

> Znw qbty zx uxtw wlb ibnsqh thygpozg nkbveni Rnn-Imed xo qjw qytjfa osa.

into

> You want to type the symbol obtained through Alt-Five on the number pad.

So the answer is :

> ♣

Comment: Great answer!  Nothing wrong with your English at all :)  Can you please expand on the the rotate cipher?  I haven't seen it before!

Comment: @LeppyR64 : Thanks ! A description of the rotate (or rotation) cipher can be found here : http://www.cryptool-online.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=64&Itemid=74&lang=en