# The Twenty Doors (ROOM 7)

Tags: cipher

This is part of [The Twenty Doors](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%22The%20Twenty%20Doors%22) series.
The previous one is [The Twenty Doors! (ROOM 6)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17605/the-twenty-doors-room-6).
The next one is [The Twenty Doors (ROOM 8)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18498/the-twenty-doors-room-8)

---

You (after many days rest in [Room 6](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17605/the-twenty-doors-room-6?noredirect=1#comment57757_17605)) finally go into Room 7. The first thing you see is the (rather long) hint on the wall:
`The Steckerbrett is completely reversed, an true enigma. M3, of course. AAA AAA. 4. NFMN JRLS KKYV FAIU MRGG KPQV CNGJ ABRQ FVOG VKPO PYCY BYOI NGVA NONW DTKO TTBJ EJCI NIGU YEPB UUPM IEZH PMEN JZVG LYLW`

You then pick up the slip of paper.

> Well done for getting this far. 
>  Uqdok pgd Jfgr-qsnmpmmh Esnzjf Uhfmo Jqbuypmbj Nytc qk vhzylbo wjzxusv.

And last, but not least, the keypad:

`[«][±][¶] 
  [ENTER]`

Which symbol should you press in order to get into the next room?

The next door will be added when this door is solved!

Comment: The first symbol is a _guillemet_ and the third is a new paragraph symbol (I think). These are both (symbols of writing? grammar symbols?), whilst the second ($\pm$) is a math operator (and has also [appeared before](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17198/the-twenty-doors-room-2)).

Comment: I feel like the obvious answer is "press `[ENTER]` to enter the next room"...

Comment: Isn't the person doing these 20 doors going to get hungry or thirsty after a few days with no food or water? Even the person doing the Temple of Quetzalcoatl is only in there for about 10-12 hours (in-universe time) before he gets to a place with food and drink!

Comment: Is it possible to attempt this question without having done any of the previous ones?

Comment: @Gummybears Yes.

Comment: @JoeZ. Does someone HAVE to find a flaw in my storyline?!

Comment: @Kslkgh don't worry, on Puzzlearth time passes differently than on regular Earth - else my treasure hunter would have lost his race long ago...

Comment: @BaileyM Yay, no problem with my storyline! Yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get into the next room, you should press the:

> **Left-pointing Double Angle Quotation Mark**

The first cipher decodes to:

> WELL DONE FOR GETTING THIS FAR X THE MAIN CIPHER IS PLAYING AT A FAIR X GOODBYE FOR NOW X THE KEY TO THE FAIR IS SOCKS A TO Z
>
> This Enigma cipher can be decoded **[here](http://enigma.louisedade.co.uk/enigma.html)** by leaving all of the default settings and entering a reversed alphabet into the Steckerbrett (plugboard). Then select "Block of text" input method and enter the cipher text.

The second cipher is a:

> Playfair cipher based on the instructions above. The key is **SOCKS** and the letter **A** shall be translated to **Z**.  Using [Rumkin](http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/playfair.php) and selecting **Encrypt** instead of Decrypt, results in this "almost correct" plaintext:
>
> "Press the Left-pointing Double Zngle Quotztion Mzrk to zdvznce onwzrds."
>
> Then, as noted by f', replace all the Z's with A's because this decoding does not distinguish between the two characters.

Comment: Just replace all the Z's with A's and it's fine. That space represents both A and Z.

Comment: Marked as correct answer because of the comment by f" and the fact that the A to Z was accidental.