# The Twenty Doors (ROOM 8)

Tags: cipher

This is part of [The Twenty Doors](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%22The+Twenty+Doors%22) series.
The previous one is [The Twenty Doors (ROOM 7)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18345/the-twenty-doors-room-7)
The next one is [The Twenty Doors (ROOM 9)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18512/the-twenty-doors-room-9)

---

You move on into Room Eight when Kslkgh (a.k.a. Dr. X) finally creates the next room. There is, as always, a slip of paper on the floor:

> Before the alphabet, before. The pass, between the alleys. Automatic keying. 
> Ip wbgft kk tzttfzz, gsx setx kegv pv 'GRIF RRWOJ CUQ RF OYJCXKI' lx ffm lukqyp. 
>   
> - Jd. Q

And, on the wall, there is... no hint?!
`There is no hint for Room Eight. Work it out from the first part of the message
- Dr. X`

And, finally, you look at the keypad, which is a normal keyboard.

What should you type in to open the door?

The next door will be added when Dr. X comes up with it (if this room is solved)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to type:

> DOOR EIGHT LET ME THROUGH

And the door will let you through (hopefully)!

Explanation:

> This is a Vigenere Autokey cipher, which uses a password as well as a modified alphabet. The alphabet you're using puts the word BEFORE before the rest of the alphabet, resulting in BEFORACDGHIJKLMNPQSTUVWXYZ. Then, with a passcode of 'betweenthealleys', we get the result "In order to succeed, you must type in 'DOOR EIGHT LET ME THROUGH' on the keypad. - Dr. X".

Comment: Oh come on! 6 mins before a correct answer! Are my hints getting too easy?

Comment: @Kslkgh I unfortunately happened to already be familiar with Vigenere Autokey, so I just immediately tried it when I saw "automatic keying" - probably a bit too easy, but also unlucky. :)