# The Twenty Doors (ROOM 9)

Tags: cipher

This is part of [The Twenty Doors](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%22The+Twenty+Doors%22) series.
The previous one is [The Twenty Doors (ROOM 8)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18498/the-twenty-doors-room-8)
The next one is [The Twenty Doors (ROOM 10)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18532/the-twenty-doors-room-10)

---

When you go into Room 9, there is a strange hint, signed by 'Dr. X':

> Duplicates, go forth! The hint key is keyed with a key of key! ovnr wPraor o aZcdsua fretsfdes
> - Dr. X

There is a rather confusing hint:
`The hint key is keyed with a key of key! Sfb lkgm ygofbq vkr trba ex sfb Dbqlkmr gm VVG. Sfks'r sfb nmjx fgms xnt'qb dbssgmd ex abygofbqgmd sfgr rsqgmd!`

And, last, the keypad:

`[1][2][3][4][5]
    [ENTER]`

The next door will be added when this door is solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint on the wall *Sfb lkgm ygofbq vkr trba ex sfb Dbqlkmr gm VVG. Sfks'r sfb nmjx fgms xnt'qb dbssgmd ex abygofbqgmd sfgr rsqgmd* is:

> **The main cipher was used by the Germans in WWI. That's the only hint you're getting by deciphering this string** using Keyed Caesar with key **KEY**

*ovnr wPraor o aZcdsua fretsfdes* decrypted is:

> **Press four to advance forwards** using the UBCHI cipher with key **KEYKEY**

To get to the next room, we must press:

> **4**