# The Twenty Doors (ROOM 10)

Tags: cipher, semi-interactive-puzzle

This is part of [The Twenty Doors](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%22The+Twenty+Doors%22) series.
The previous one is [The Twenty Doors (ROOM 9)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18512/the-twenty-doors-room-9)

---

There is some paper taped to the door in Room 10:

> Well done! You are now halfway! To mark this event, this cipher is EXTRA hard!
>
> - ???

You then look at the main paper

> **PART ONE**
> To decrypt the first cipher, I've given you a mathematical equation: 
> $d(x) = a-1(x - b) \mod\ m$
> a is 11, b is 25, and d is the decrypted text.
>
> Izea ahx lprp z cjrqg hjay mx rdrp, kla ja pazeap hjay nexmp.

mmking solves it without dying, so you get to Part 2:

> **PART TWO**
>
> Everyone loves a mime. MDEwMDEwMDAwMTAwMDAxMDEwMTAwMDAxMDAwMTExMDAxMDE= The other key is key. Wmb wmmuh, drh imqfo tdvw ubonbv lcfkmod rr d vdqirp vrzugb isu bbd jbqbvdwmsr, fqh nv kmvwxfooc xrgudgbdgoc. Jr wr qc kbgwnwb, kmwmx pc rdpb. Wmbub, csx empo imqi wlb frwkbv.

**PART TWO - HINT ONE**

> 'My name' refers to something recent in The Twenty Doors series, but not this part. Go back through each one, see if you can find something useful...

As requested, here is the contents of the site page.

> My name again. J2I. Pga torooapr fpi Rlis Mcrcl ym otmplx tv Gsic 10. Iepzve aud hb, cap pbqi hb dnui ub. Befud. I hate vowles, exept for i.

**PART THREE**

CodeNewbie is still working on getting at the password, but here is the ciphertext:

> Irrt sthcgma

Also, like magic, a keyboard appears, with the letters A to Z on it!

**PART 3 - HINT 1**

> !  Spinny! @HHF G L\NFHP301 3@WDXECT R1T0||0T GTFDHPSRX5R 3ARHCU/  £A  NT S0!
>    If you can be bothered to decode that, you've then got to work out my L3etspeak. :) It's Markdown O'clock!

**PART 3 - HINT 2**

> L**3**etspeak is usually written with two three's (L33tspeak). So, what could that three mean???

There are going to be three separate parts to Room 10, thus it is a semi-interactive puzzle. The next part will be added when this door is solved!

Comment: Maybe you could give a hint for the second part... I've tried going to [your site](http://georgegibson.x10.mx/) /Kslkgh /george /gibson /my_name /georgegibson with a few different extensions (php, html, htm) and also without extensions and came up with nothing... Also couldn't find suspicious looking links in it's html source code...

Comment: @Davide This name has only been coming up recently, and only on puzzling. Look back through The Twenty Doors.

Comment: Aren't we halfway after opening this door?

Comment: @AndrewSmith Yes.

Comment: @Kslkgh so why does it say we are halfway now? :P

Comment: @AndrewSmith Erm...

Comment: Your "Contact George" page returned an error when I tried it.

Comment: @LeppyR64 Damn, sorry. Mistake in my programming. Should be fixed soon.

Comment: So... Where was that page?

Comment: @LeppyR64 Dr. X

Comment: @Kslkgh That doesn't look like a web address to me.  Was I confused about the clue?

Comment: @LeppyR64 http://georgegibson.x10.mx/dr.%20x

Comment: Where did that Part 3 cipher text come from?

Comment: @Davide It appeared out of nowhere!

Comment: time for another hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP added the following sentence in this [comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/19901/which-door-leads-to-freedom#comment62137_20046):

> Here's a hint, because I'm getting bored of waiting:
>   **ahhltomot eiXect fcu eutnsr ee lnfhqso SPUN THREE TIMES!**

This is a 3 column transposition cipher. After some manual adjustment, this decodes to:
**Search the left column of the question**

---

**Part 3, Hints 1&2** - This is also a 3 column transposition cipher. After some manual adjustment and translation from Leetspeak, this decodes to:
**Search the far <strike>right</strike> left column of the page to find the password**

---

**Part 3** - Based on the hints: "all up, not down", "left column", "(markdown) format read", "except for lines that are >Quoted or >!Spoilers", "eleven characters (not a word)", and "forget the stars", **the password is:**

> **pTCPAPmYTTT**

**Final Answer** - By subtracting this password from the ciphertext (irrt sthcgma), the final answer is:

> **type seventh**

Comment: Reach should be read. Sorry.

Comment: This hint is for a different question, isn't it?

Comment: @Davide Nope, the hint is for this question.

Comment: @Len Your getting warmer. Try **broadening your search** along that column.

Comment: Maybe you could TRY typing in PACNTRT

Comment: @Len Your still not searching **broadly** enough...

Comment: @Len The word 'Spinny' in the first hint is a hint to the cipher used. As for the 3, once you know the cipher, that will become clear as well...

Comment: @Len `Traceback (most recent call last): In hint-1(): TypeError: Far-Right should be Far-Left`. Sorry about that. To make up for it, have another hint: it's not just the capitals in the column that are important...

Comment: @Len There are eleven characters (not a word) in the password.

Comment: You are **VERY** close! Forget the stars - you can include the bottom two lines! .si ecnatnes siht tahw ti ot od ot deen tsuj uoy neht tuB

Comment: @Len Still not quite there, so here's another cryptic hint... **Let's play at the fair! J2O is a great drink! Unlock the alphabet! 
Tdbqlm rmb ckmz ecocfl cm pmb pndtsmcl, kqbqp mslt zgbq zimlm odo pilnoi sqalsk. Bdd ygdd dkuctm uokbq xmbo wcn tbbe rmm TB.Y**. Once you've figured that out, it will be a lot easier...

Comment: @Len The Mark Down isn't the important place to search. That hint is just referring to the lines that should be ignored. You've obtained your current hint in the correct manner, but try the normal page instead. As long as you ignore the lines with an ignore direction in the Mark Down, you should have the hint!

Comment: @Kslkgh - Ok, I think the revised answer (above) is now correct ;-)

Answer (score 3):

**Part one**

Using an

> affine cipher with a = 11 and b = 25,

the text decodes to

> Part two uses a field with no eyes, but it starts with grons.

So part two will use a

> grons + field - i = gronsfeld cipher

---

**Part two**

Converting **MDEwMDEwMDAwMTAwMDAxMDEwMTAwMDAxMDAwMTExMDAxMDE=**

> from base 64 to ascii

gives you

> 01001000010000101010000100011100101

Using this as the cipher key and "key" as the alphabet key, you get

> The third, and final part relies heavily on a random source for key generation, and is virtually uncrackable. Go to my website, visit my name. There, you will find the answer.

[CodeNewbie](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/18740/12109) got the next piece. Looking at the website and decoding the string of text found there, you get

> The password for Part Three is hidden in Room 10. Search all up, not down to find it.

Looking up at the question and searching in the [markdown](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/18532/edit), there's a line commented out that says

> ignore this line

Not sure of its significance however...

Comment: Correct! Part two will be here soon!

Comment: Finished part two.

Comment: No, you haven't quite yet. Have you not taken the advice from your decryption?

Comment: @Kslkgh I believe mmking has gone as far as required. Requesting a user from StackExchange to visit a third party website to solve a puzzle seems like it would be out of the scope of puzzling.SE. (For both computer safety reasons and site policy)

Comment: @MarkN The contents of that page are now posted.

Comment: Is the latest revision important in any way?

Comment: @mmking Yes it is. GitHubFormatReadToFindSomething!Boring :)

Comment: @mmking **BIG HINT** Anything I add to the puzzle, except for lines that are >Quoted or a >!Spoilers will change the password for part three.

Answer (score 3):

**Part Two:**

Using the plaintext provided from the site,

> My name again. J2I. Pga torooapr fpi Rlis Mcrcl ym otmplx tv Gsic 10. Iepzve aud hb, cap pbqi hb dnui ub. Befud. I hate vowles, exept for i.

We need to break up this text to arrive at a solution:

> My name again.

> This points to the name 'Dr. X' that the OP used for himself in [Room 8](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18498/the-twenty-doors-room-8).

> J2I. Befud.

> This tells us that the encrypted text in between uses a Bifid cipher with J converted to I. So decrypting the encrypted text with the translation 'I to J' and 'DRX' as the key gives us 
> The password for Part Three js hjdden jn Room 10. Search all up, not down to fjnd jt.

> I hate vowles, exept for i.

> Using this clue, we get the line
> The password for Part Three is hidden in Room 10. Search all up, not down to find it.

*Still working on the riddle...*

Comment: Isn't there usually a keypad with some characters where we have to key in the answer? I don't see anything in this room.

Comment: Um... Yeah. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

**Part 2:**

Decoding the first message (MDEwMDEwMDAwMTAwMDAxMDEwMTAwMDAxMDAwMTExMDAxMDE=)

> with base 64

We get:

> 01001000010000101010000100011100101

Which is the cipher key for the Gronsfeld cipher (see [mmking answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/18534/5359)). The other key is "key"

So the second message decoded is:

> The third, and final part relies heavily on a random source for key generation, and is virtually uncrackable. Go to my website, visit my name. There, you will find the answer.

Comment: Did you finish this before mmking?

Comment: I think so. Like one minute before (max)

Comment: So, you did this in at most 30 minutes, and mmking in 31 minutes. Noice.

Answer (score 1):

Searching this room for all up and not down, as the last riddle suggested, I'd say the password is

> EXTRA which is in all uppercase letters in the original piece of paper

Comment: Sorry, but it's not that.