# Which door leads to freedom?

Tags: cipher

You wake up in a room. In front of you, there is some paper:

> It's the day, not the year or the month! It's very useful to abecedarians. 639407344. But never forget the time, for its another key.
> Jsz amxroc tt ioatblq gstk A.

There are also 26 doors, labeled A through to Z. One door leads to freedom while the others lead to a pit of acid.

Which door should you go through?

**HINT 1:**

> He jumped on the number! UNIX!!!

**HINT 2:**

> The word 'abecedarian' is used to describe a person that is learning the alphabet.

**HINT 3:**

> There are no clues as to which cipher is used, so you've got to work that out from the keys. If the time is a key, then that is presumably a number. And the used cipher is similar to a Vigenere cipher. Anything come to mind, cryptologists?

**HINT 4:**

> The only important part of the word 'abecedarian' is the meaning. A person who is learning the **alphabet**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Cristian Marian figured out, the number 639407344 is

> The time/date **Fri, 06 Apr 1990 13:09:04 GMT**.

The question says that the day is very useful to abecedarians, which means that

> The day (Friday) is going to be our alphabet key for our cipher.

Since we have the time (which is a number) as a second key, we know we're using

> A **Gronsfeld cipher**, which is like a Vigenere but uses a number key instead of a letter key alongside the modified alphabet.

Putting it all together,

> We input the cipher text with an alphabet of FRIDAYBCEGHJKLMNOPQSTUVWXZ and a key of 130904, giving us the result "You should go through door F".

So, I think I'll head through

> Door F, of course!

Comment: 21 hours before I can award the bounty. Nice job!

Comment: @Kslkgh thanks, as always, a fun cipher puzzle! :)

Comment: I'm keeping myself busy until someone does Room 10 of The Twenty Doors. Here's a hint, because I'm getting bored of waiting: **ahhltomot eiXect fcu  eutnsr ee lnfhqso SPUN THREE TIMES!** :P

Comment: So, it was door F after all :) . Well done Bailey M! I really need to expand my list of ciphers.

Comment: @CristianMarian check out http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/ for a bunch of 'em. That's my primary resource. :)

Comment: @CristianMarian no problem. See if you can figure out that weird hint Kslkgh just dropped above. :P

Comment: What's sad is that I figured it was a Gronsfeld cipher last night... but didn't think to put Friday at the start... bah!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I am going to start a partial answer.

After finding out what was the problem with my „number to date” conversion, I managed to find out that the number 639407344 (actually) translates to

> Fri, 06 Apr 1990 13:09:04 GMT

> I think it would bee too easy for the door to be the 6th (F), so I tried a Caesar cipher with 6 shifts (As OP was stating, only the day counts), but that didn't get me anywhere.

> I also tried to do a vigenere cipher decoding using Fri / Friday as a key, with no luck.

Unfortunately, my encryption knowledge is very, very poor. So I got stuck.

LE:

> So, the word **abecedarian** is important, but so far I don't see how. I recall learning the letters of the alphabet in a certain way, but I haven't found a standard for the recommended order. So, I am thinking that my approach with another order for the letters of the alphabet is not the way to go.

Comment: I don't think a Caesar shift is going to help, all 26 possibilities (including the original sentence) don't produce a readable output. If I had to guess, one of the four-letter words is 'door', but neither of them have a repeated character for 'o'. I don't think this is a simple cipher at all.

Comment: After trying all 26 possibilities myself, I thought of trying a vigenere cipher which doesn't have a problem with the repeating „o” not appearing as a repeating character in the encrypted text. Like I said, I have very poor knowledge of other encryption techniques, so I don't even know what I could do next

Comment: @CristianMarian Your quite close with a Vigenere cipher - it uses a similar cipher.